# how to set radio button check from intent in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to set the radio button checked by taking the value from the previous activity through intent. But it's not working.

Here's the intent I send from the MyProfileActivity to EditProfileActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("nameResult", nameResult);
                intent.putExtra("emailResult", emailResult);
                intent.putExtra("phoneResult", phoneResult);
                intent.putExtra("genderResult", genderResult);
                intent.putExtra("dobResult", dobResult);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Here's the intents I'm receiving from MyProfileActivity,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    binding.updateName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("nameResult"));
    binding.updateEmail.setText(intent.getStringExtra("emailResult"));
    binding.updateNumber.setText(intent.getStringExtra("phoneResult"));
    String selectedRadioTxt = getIntent().getStringExtra("genderResult");
    binding.updateDob.setText(intent.getStringExtra("dobResult"));
```

I want to set the radio button checked. I have also checked the value using toast and made sure that value is coming right. Now the value is coming male. But the radio button male is not getting selected after this code.

```
String male = "male";
String female = "female";

RadioButton maleButton = findViewById(R.id.male);
RadioButton femaleButton = findViewById(R.id.female);

    if(selectedRadioTxt.equals(male)){
        maleButton.setChecked(true);
        Toast.makeText(this, male, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(selectedRadioTxt.equals(female)){
        femaleButton.setChecked(true);
        Toast.makeText(this, female, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Here is the xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EditProfile" >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/editDp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/updateName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/amarante"
        android:hint="@string/full_name"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editDp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/updateEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/amarante"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/updateName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/updateName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/updateName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/updateNumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/amarante"
        android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/updateEmail"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/updateEmail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/updateEmail" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/updateDob"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/amarante"
        android:hint="@string/date_of_birth"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/updateGender"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/updateGender"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/updateGender" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:text="@string/update"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/updateDob"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/updateDob"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/updateDob"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/updateGender"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/updateNumber"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/updateNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/updateNumber">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/male"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/amarante"
            android:onClick="checkButton"
            android:text="@string/male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/female"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/amarante"
            android:onClick="checkButton"
            android:text="@string/female" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/other"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/amarante"
            android:onClick="checkButton"
            android:text="@string/other" />
    </RadioGroup>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But it's not getting selected.

Comment: You are getting a string with id `R.id.male` by using **String#valueOf(int)** method. Shouldn't you be using [Context#getString(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getString(int)) method instead? As in, `getString(R.id.male)`?

Comment: tried this,   if(selectedRadioTxt.equals(getString(R.id.male))){
            binding.male.setChecked(true);
            Toast.makeText(this, "male", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(selectedRadioTxt.equals(getString(R.id.female))){
            binding.female.setChecked(true);
            Toast.makeText(this, "female", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }     but not working

Answer (score 0):

None gets checked cause the `String.valueOf(R.id.male)` returns a value different from what you are equating it to in the if statement.

`String.valueOf(R.id.male)` is an int which is just converted to a string. Meaning `selectedRadioTxt` can never be equal to `String.valueOf(R.id.male) or String.valueOf(R.id.female)`

In other wards:Eg. `selectedRadioTx = "male"` but `String.valueOf(R.id.male) ="some Int vale eg 20133321"`

**Solution**
Change your if statement to:

```
if(selectedRadioTxt.trim().equals("male")){
        binding.male.setChecked(true);
        Toast.makeText(this, "male", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(selectedRadioTxt.trim().equals("female")){
        binding.female.setChecked(true);
        Toast.makeText(this, "female", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Make sure you take note of the caps on the Strings male != Male, and female != "Female". Make sure the value u get from intent `selectedRadioTx` either equals male or female as per for the solution in the if statement.

Comment: Tried the same sir. But still it's not working. When I go to that activity the radio buttons are still being unchecked.

Comment: What is the value of selectedRadioTxt?

Comment: And the exact value showing in the previous activity is male. This was I'm sending through intent.

Comment: can you please toast selectedRadioTxt in the EditProfileActivity and see what value you get. or else share the code in the previous activity

Comment: Yes sir, tried doing that. Value is coming male

Comment: lets have a look at EditProfileActivity class and its corresponding xml(layout file), i think you must be mis using binding.

Comment: am updating the answer

Comment: Probably add a trim to selected selectedRadioTxt:

if(selectedRadioTxt.trim().equals("male")){
//...
} else if(selectedRadioTxt.trim().equals("male"){
//....
}

Answer (score 0):

Can you check value of  **genderResult** in first activity before intent

Comment: it's male there.

Comment: So you have problem to set value of gender in first activity 
Can you add code of first activity please

Comment: There it's setting it's value as male only

Answer (score 0):

As you are using RadioGroup, can you please try

```
RadioGroup gender = findViewById(R.id.updateGender);

if(selectedRadioTxt.trim().equals(male.trim())) {
    gender.check(R.id.male);
} else {
    gender.check(R.id.female);
}
```

I used `trim()` to remove unnecessary spaces. You can avoid if not necessary.

**UPDATE**

This is full functional code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String genderResult = "male";

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("genderResult", genderResult);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        String male = "male";
        String female = "female";

        String selectedRadioTxt = getIntent().getStringExtra("genderResult");

        RadioGroup gender = findViewById(R.id.gender);

        if(selectedRadioTxt.equals(male)) {
            gender.check(R.id.male);
        } else if(selectedRadioTxt.equals(female)) {
            gender.check(R.id.female);
        }

    }
}
```

activity_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/male"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Male" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/female"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you check the selectedRadioTxt value on Toast? I am seeing it is printing the male variable. Your other codes seem fine.

Comment: I updated the answer with functional code. It is working fine on my side.